# ASP.Net: ClientID not correct in code-behind of a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, clientid

The following code does not work. The markup is in a User Control and I suppose that's why ClientID returns the wrong prefix for the TextBox id.

Markup:

```
<INPUT id="txtName" runat="server" maxlength="50" style="WIDTH:100px">
<INPUT type="button" value="Find Your Doctor" id="btnFind" runat="server"
      style="MARGIN-LEFT:10px;WIDTH:130px">
```

Code-Behind:

```
btnFind.Attributes.Add("onClick",string.Format("DoctorLink
        ('{0}',document.getElementById('{1}').value,{2});",
        row["ZipCode"],
        txtName.ClientID));
```

Results in browser:

```
<input name="DoctorsMainArea1$ctl01$txtName" type="text"
   id="DoctorsMainArea1_ctl01_txtName" maxlength="50" style="WIDTH:100px" />

<input name="DoctorsMainArea1$ctl01$btnFind" type="button" 
   id="DoctorsMainArea1_ctl01_btnFind" value="Find Your Doctor" style="MARGIN-
   LEFT:10px;WIDTH:130px" onClick="PrepareDoctorLink('90210',
   document.getElementById('DoctorsMainArea1_ctl00_txtName').value);" />
```

As you can see, the parameter for the JavaScript call is `DoctorsMainArea1_ctl00_txtName`, but the actual id of the input element is `DoctorsMainArea1_ctl01_txtName`.

Any idea how to fix this? jQuery? I am not so much interested in an explanation of what's going on (maybe there is another control on this page that is interfering), but a more robust way to solve the problem.

Comment: why do you need to use document.getElementById when its the onclick event for the same control you're trying to retrieve? Can you not just use "this" (which will return the input box. Then you wont even need to try and work out the id, and you wont need runat="server".

Comment: The onclick handler for the button is put together server-side because I need the zip code and other parameters that I removed to make the code easier to read.

Comment: Are you changing the control tree _after_ reading ClientID?

Comment: Possibly. The ClientId is read in the Page_Init() event. There is so much going on in this app that I cannot answer the question with certainty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try moving the code that adds the onclick attribute to the button in the **PreRender** event (or OnPreRender override) in your page or user-control. That should probably get the ClientID right.

Comment: It was in the Page_Init event. We moved it into the page load event and it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know which asp.net version you are using but in 4.0 you can declare inside any server control  ClientIDMode="static" and it will give you the exact id in browser.

Example:

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtName" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static"/>
```

Others are predictable, inherit and it can be used with ClientIdRowsuffix.Can be used at page level and even on master pages and even in web.config file.

Example on web.config file:

```
<system.web>
<Pages clientIDMode="predictable"/>
other system web properties
</system.web>
```

Watched Craig shoemaker's Video at tekpub, you can also read more about it at Rick's blog[link text](https://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/54760.aspx). It's pretty cool tho.

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution:

```
btnFind.Attributes.Add("onClick",string.Format("DoctorLink
        ('{0}',document.getElementById('{1}').value,{2});",
        row["ZipCode"],
        "DoctorsMainArea1_ctl01_" + txtName.ClientID));
```

This happens because you have a content placeholder in your page somewhere.

Comment: Fast maybe, but not very robust :-)

Comment: Not robust, you're right. If you were using ASP.NET 4 you'd have a better support for Client IDs. Things changed for better. Thanks God!

Answer (score 0):

another solution:
html tag:

```
<input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" />
```

code-bind:

```
string txtName_value = Request.Forms["txtName"];
```

and you can get the value

just use the html control.

Comment: ps: don't give the repeat name in the page, it will become a string that like "value1,value2"

Comment: Like I said, this is a user control and your solution does not work for multiple instances of the control on one page. Since in this case there won't be more than one, and if nothing better comes up, I may still use your suggestion (until it breaks the page the next time). I still believe that this can be done more elegantly with jQuery.